# mips read int from user as half word

Tags: assembly, mips, short

well , i have this assignment below in mips that requires read three integer form the user as short (half-word),my problem is how to read and store this integer as half word .
I wrote the program but I miss the part (half-word) Can someone help me with this?

the question :

Write a well-documented MIPS assembly program that defines three variables a, b, c as
short (halfwords), prompts the user to read from the keyboard three unsigned values for
a, b, c, calculates f and t as shown below, and then prints the entered and calculated values
in separate lines in proper (readable) format .

f = 15 * c / b + a % b

t = 10 * f / (a - b)

my code :

```
## data section
.data 
# 'a'lf I/O
a_input_ingerer: .asciiz "please enter a :"
a_output_ingerer: .asciiz "a= "

# 'b' I/O
b_input_ingerer: .asciiz "please enter b :"
b_output_ingerer: .asciiz " ,b= "

# 'c' I/O
c_input_ingerer: .asciiz "please enter c :"
c_output_ingerer: .asciiz " ,c="

# outputs
f_output_ingerer: .asciiz ",f= "
t_output_ingerer: .asciiz "t="

#equations
f_equation: .asciiz "\n f = 15 * c / b + a % b\n "
t_equation: .asciiz "\n t = 10 * f / (a - b)\n"


newline:.asciiz "\n"
newline_hastags: .asciiz "\n################\n "
newline_tab: .asciiz "\n \t"
newline_hastag: .asciiz "\n#"

## error massage
error:.asciiz "your number out of range"

###############
#code section
.text
.globl main

main:
##############################
## 'a'
##print the String

    la   $a0,a_input_ingerer
    li   $v0,4
    syscall 

##get the input
    la  $v0,5
    syscall  

## store the input in register $t1

    move $t1,$v0

#########
## 'b'
##print the String

    la   $a0,b_input_ingerer
    li   $v0,4
    syscall 

##get the input
    li $v0,5
    syscall  

## store the input in register $t2
    move $t2,$v0

#########
## 'a'
##print the String

    la   $a0,c_input_ingerer
    li   $v0,4
    syscall 

##get the input
    li $v0,5
    syscall  

## store the input in register $t3
    move $t3,$v0

#########

#calcolation
# f=(15*c/b)+(a%b)
#(15*c/b) save it at $t4
    sll $t4,$t3,0
    sll $t5,$t3,1
    sll $t6,$t3,2
    sll $t7,$t3,3

    add $t4,$t5,$t4
    add $t4,$t6,$t4
    add $t4,$t7,$t4

    div $t4,$t2
    mflo $t4
#(a%b)
    div $t1,$t2
    mfhi $t5

# (15*c/b)+(a%b)
# $t4  + $t5 save it $t4
    add $t4,$t5,$t4

######
# t=10*f/(a-b
# 10*f and save it in $t5
    sll $t5,$t4,1
    sll $t6,$t4,3
    add $t5,$t5,$t6

#(a-b)and save it in $t6
    sub $t6,$t1,$t2

# 10*f / (a-b) and save it in $t5
# $t5 / $t6
    div $t5,$t6
    mflo $t5

########################## 
#Output
#first equation input
    la $a0, a_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    move $a0,$t1

    li $v0,1
    syscall


    la $a0,b_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    move $a0,$t2

    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0,c_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    move $a0,$t3

    li $v0,1
    syscall

##first equation

    la $a0,f_equation
    li $v0,4
    syscall

#first equation result

    la $a0,f_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    move $a0,$t4
  
    li $v0,1
    syscall

###############################
    la $a0,newline_hastags
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

#second equation input

    la $a0, a_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    move $a0,$t1

    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0,b_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall 

    move $a0,$t2

    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0,f_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    move $a0,$t4

    li $v0,1
    syscall


##second equation
    la $a0,t_equation
    li $v0,4
    syscall

#second equation result 
    la $a0,t_output_ingerer
    li $v0,4
    syscall 
  
    move $a0,$t5

    li $v0,1
    syscall

#######################################

#system call for termainating the exeuction

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: `li  $v0,5` / `syscall` reads an integer into `$v0`.  You can store the low 16 bits of that if you want with `sh`, truncating it.  If the value is in the [-32768, 32767] range, those 16 bits will still represent the same value, because the high 16 bits were not significant.  Or if you want to do `(int)(short)x` in registers, left-shift by 16 then arithmetic right shift by 16, to sign-extend the low 16 into the full register, so the full register has a value that a `short` could have.

Comment: Can you give me an example @Peter Cordes

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ has MIPS GCC installed; you can write some tiny C functions and look at the asm output to see for example how to load from an `unsigned short`, or store an `int` into one.